# using ‘-Wcast-qual’ option to check the compilation

Tags: c, gcc

I am reading [an introduction to gcc](http://www.tunl.duke.edu/documents/public/root/material/5/An_Introduction_to_GCC-Brian_Gough.pdf) in which it says:

> ‘-Wcast-qual’ this option warns about pointers that are cast to remove
>   a type qualifier, such as const. For example, the following function
>   discards the const qualifier from its input argument, allowing it to
>   be overwritten:
>
> ```
>  void
>        f (const char * str)
>        {
>          char * s = (char *)str;
>          s[0] = ’\0’; }
> ```
>
> The modification of the original contents of str is a violation of its
>   const property. This option will warn about the improper cast of the
>   variable str which allows the string to be modified.

I tried to repeat this, **expecting a warning, but there's no warning** when it is compiled. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(const char * str);

int main() {
    char Str = 'a';
    char * myStr;
    myStr = & Str;
    printf ("result: %c \n", * myStr);
    f(myStr);
    printf ("result: %c \n", * myStr);
    return 0;
}


void
f (const char * str)
{
  char * s = (char *)str;
  s[0] = '\0';
}
```

the command is : `gcc -Wcast-qual castqual.c`

Can anyone explain this inconsistency?

Comment: Are you by any chance using a mac where gcc is actually a wrapper for clang? clang doesn't report this issue on the currently released OS (if you've got the developer beta for 10.11, it *will* report the error)

Comment: @Petesh very likely, compiling his example on Linux produces `castqual.c:19:14: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]`

Comment: @petesh I think that is the point. So do you have any idea how to use the "real" gcc instead? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to use the real gcc, you'll have to install it. On my mac I've installed the real gcc via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) but you could also use macports (or something else). Once it's installed, you run it using gcc-version (e.g. gcc-4.9, gcc-5 - depends on what you install), and it should show the relevant warning.

Comment: @petesh Ummm, that is wired. I think I have installed it by Homebrew.  Here's the result that I ran command "gcc-4.8 --version":         "lihangdeMacBook-Pro:03 lihang$ gcc-4.8 --version
gcc-4.8 (Homebrew gcc48 4.8.4) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. "

Comment: @petesh But if I ran command "gcc --version", it shows "Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix"  I don't know how to configure this....

Comment: Yes, so when you want to run the 'real' gcc, you use `gcc-4.8` rather than just `gcc` and it should produce the correct warning. You can, if you wish, make a link from gcc to gcc-4.8, but I prefer to leave it named like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, it turns out that the OP is using a mac, where `gcc` as a command is a wrapper around `clang` - the llvm based compiler.

The version of clang that's being used accepts the option but does nothing with it. Support for the warning is being added and should appear in the XCode 7/clang 7 timeframe; however the question was about `gcc` and not about `clang`.

In this case, you need to install a proper copy of gcc using, either manually or using a package manager such as [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/). Once you've installed gcc, it becomes available as, for example, `gcc-4.8`, `gcc-5`, etc (depends on the package manager). When you want to compile code with actual gcc, you use: `gcc-4.8 -Wcast-qual testcode.c`. If you're using autoconf tools you can use `export CC=gcc-4.8; export CXX=g++-4.8`, etc. and then that compiler will be picked up by the package.

Verifying that you're calling `gcc`, rather than `clang` requires checking the output from `gcc --version`. On a clang wrapper you see things like:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

whereas on an actual gcc instance you see:

```
$ gcc-5 --version
gcc-5 (Homebrew gcc 5.1.0) 5.1.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

> imho aside: you can make a symlink to the specific `gcc-4.8` called `gcc`, and get it to invoke directly like that but it can break other things.